# Cache API response

Tags: javascript, node.js

Our web Application which is in Angular has dependency on **third party API** which return JSON object in repsonse and most of time it's performance is horrible because we can't timeout the API call it's data is important. Is there any way to introduce a cache db which get the data from third party API and stored it or some API cache mechanism? If yes then how the data will be updated what will be the mechanism of updating the cache data when the actual data updated.

I don't want to cache data on client side because it will not be available to all users. I am talking about a centralized cache db or API Cache whose data can be consistent and up to date.

Thanks

Comment: @Jack Bashford it's just a API call that we normally do in Angular the actual question is that third API response is slow and need to add some cache storage. So I don't think we need code example for that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Without more info on your app architecture, for example is the 3rd party API call done client or server side or are the call results different per user/time/etc, it's difficult to answer this question. From a high level caching logic is something like, check cache, if found and not timed out, return that value. If not found, get from source and update cache value with a TTL.

Answer (score 2):

@Sohail If the API performance is bad, it probably will not help much to use cache on client side. I think you can use something like the following to ensure smoother experience for your web app's users.

You haven't mentioned your server-side infrastructure. So, YMMV.

1. A background service that `polls` 3rd party API and stores data on your server. This frees up your web app from polling under-performing API.
2. Use push mechanism from background service (e.g. `socket.io`, `WebSocket`, or similar) to send `new data` events to your web app running in the browser which then polls data from your server (not 3rd party API). This makes it cleaner and leaner with clear responsibilities for each component in your ecosystem (web app, background service that calls 3rd party API, and your own API that just returns the data that is stored as a result of polling 3rd party API).

I agree that it is little more work, but it will make all aspects of your app easier to maintain.

Comment: it's third party API

Comment: @Sohail: I understand that it's 3rd party API and it's not in your control. The changes I have suggested are meant to be done in your own backend and frontend.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this varies hugely depending on many factors, mostly regarding what the API is returning. Since you are requesting it often I'm assuming it changes, but you're wanting to cache so there must be some time between updates - the easiest way to do this would be to make a request to the API that only returns version information (or some other ID, timestamp, whatever) that you can check against your latest API request, and if there is a difference, you will know that you need to make a request to the API.

Depending on what the data you are caching is, one option could be to store the response on your server (cache/latest_api_response.json for example). Every time the app loads and the API request is made, it first checks the local response data and if possible checks the remote version to see if it needs to be updated (or you can, say, check if the data is <1hr old, etc depending on your needs), and if it doesn't, simply return your data in the same manner that you would return the downloaded data from the API.

As others have pointed out, there are existing caching solutions, and there really are a million ways to deal with this, so it does depend heavily on what you're trying to work with!

Comment: I am searching for something like this https://hollow.how/quick-start/ but want to cache API cache data which return JSON object in response.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to cache data either in a global namespace variable which could be used across all your components or use a cache library for example js-cache

```
<script src="bundle/cache.js"></script> 
<script>
    cache.set('lorem', 'ipsum', 60000);
    console.log(cache.get('lorem'));
</script>
```

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Normal HTTP caching can be used.  No need to reinvent in, we have standard headers for this.  If you needed more specific control (such as offline response handling), that's what service workers are for.

Comment: When I said global namespace variable I mean a store like component to cache data within your project which is normal HTTP caching . Sorry if It got conveyed wrongly

Comment: I understand what you meant, and no, this isn't normal HTTP caching.  The browser handles cached responses for you if you do it right.